# working with different forms within mdi application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application using C# wherein I have a form which is MdiContainer form named `parentmdiform` in which all my child form gets open.

From submenu of this `parentmdiform` a form named `studentmasterform` gets open.from this form on a click of a button a new form named existingstudent form gets open.

When I want go back to `studentmasterform` again from `Existingstudentform`, a click of  a button on which `studentmasterform` gets open.But the problem is my earlier opened `studentmasterform` from parent form does not get focused or disposed off.That means I get two separate object of same form that is Studentmasterform which exists in my `parentmdiform`.

What I want is ,that same form object should get either focused or disposed of when i click on any other forms within my MDI application to access earlier form.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the creation of `studentmasterform`. And if it is there, created, don't create new one, do `Keyboard.Focus(oldOne);`

P.S. There is `studentmasterform.Closed` event to help you keep the track.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what are you want to do.
First, if you want that a Form closes if it loses focus, take a look at the "Deactivate" event of the Form class. [MSDN Deactive Event]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx

When you need a Form as only once opened, you can check "parentmdiform.MdiChildren" to get all the children of your MDI From. You can give your Forms an unique name, so it's easier to focus the right.

regards, C#er